# How to Query case insensitive in Alfresco Solr search?

Tags: solr, full-text-search, alfresco, case-insensitive

Using Alfresco Community - 5.0.0 version.

Below query using Solr returned result :

```
1st Query : select cmis:objectId from TEST:doc where TEST:docType = 'Type1'
```

But we want the case-insensitive search if there are docType value 'type1' || 'TYPE1' || 'tYpe1' || 'Type1' then it should give same number of records.

The 2nd Query works fine while **"Trying DB query DbOrIndexSwitchingQueryLanguage"** fetch, but **"Using SOLR query DbOrIndexSwitchingQueryLanguage"** not returning any result.

```
2nd Query: select cmis:objectId from TEST:doc where LOWER(TEST:docType) = 'type1'
```

But while using LOWER it's execution time is much higher. For example, if the 1st query takes 10ms then 2nd takes around 3 seconds.

What is the syntax to search in Alfresco Solr case insensitive or is there another way to resolve this performance issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to make a CMIS search case-insensitive when using Alfresco as the CMIS repository. [Here is a thread](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/177605-cmis-search-by-cmisname-case-sensitive) in the Alfresco forums that discusses this issue.